# User's data and local storage in cordova app

Tags: cordova, local-storage

I have a webapp which saves user's data in local storage. I want to use cordova to port in mobile (e.g. apk). If I release an update (another apk) the user's data are lost? I must substitute necessarily local storage with filesystem?

Comment: When using Cordova, data in LocalStorage remains accessible even after APK updates.

Comment: Thank you, remains accessible and the user's data are not lost?

Comment: on Android, when updating a Cordova application (by installing an updated version of the APK), the data in localstorage remains accessible an is not lost. You can try it yourself and see. However, the webapp's localstorage will be unavailable to the Cordova app.

Comment: Ok thank you very much